# Delete a record from table and all other associate tables

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

In a give database that consist of several tables,

What is the efficient way to delete data (1 record) from one main table and also from all the other associate tables.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to **define a cascading behavior for deleting on FKs**.

For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE order_items (
    ...
    order_id integer REFERENCES orders ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ...
);
```

In this case, if someone removes an order, the order items are removed as well. CASCADE specifies that when a referenced row is deleted, row(s) referencing it should be automatically deleted as well.

Reference:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html